# Kohana edit config file dynamically

Tags: php, kohana

I would like to know if we can edit dynamically the config file.

Here is my example.

```
<?php
// config/system.php

return array(
    'data'=>"content",
    'data1' => "content2",
);

?>
```

I know that we can edit it by using the set() methode, but this methode doesn't edit the file.

example :

```
<?php

// get config file array
$config = Kohana::$config->load('system');

// set the new config .. but this function doesn't edit the file !
$config->set("data","MyContent");

?>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I'd store it in a database. Either that or write some class that is able to edit config files as well.

Comment: I use some config files to add/remove Banned Ip, and use the same config file with another auth system, that's why i don't want to save it into a database, i have write a script to do that.. i'll publish it as a solution maybe this can help someone else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i did it myself, maybe this can help someone else too.

1 - Create APPPATH.'config/Group.php' and put this script.

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct script access.');

// Save this file at APPPATH.'config/Group.php'

// Extend the original Config_group
class Config_Group extends Kohana_Config_Group {

    // This function allow us to save on the config file
    public function save()
    {
        $filename = APPPATH.'config'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$this->group_name().".php";

                // test if the config file is writable or not.
        if (is_writable($filename))
        {
                        // save the array into the config file and return true/false
            return (file_put_contents($filename, "<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');".PHP_EOL
                                    ."return " . var_export($this->as_array(), true) . ";",LOCK_EX));
        }

        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

How to use :

```
<?php

// get config file array
$config = Kohana::$config->load('system');

// set the new config .. but this function doesn't edit the file !
$config->set("data","MyContent");

// Save the new file config.
$config->save();

?>
```

Comment: +1 for the effort. I would use database tho, but this could help some1.